# Pythonic way for static function variables (small scope, single initialization)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, static

```
def clean_word(word):
    chars_to_clean = {',', ':', '.','/'} #static?
    res = ''
    for c in word:
        if c not in chars_to_clean:
            res += c
    return res
```

In C++ I would have declared `chars_to_clean` as `static` so that I can minimize its scope on one hand and avoid repeated assignment on the other. How can I achieve these goals in Python?

I could make `chars_to_clean` a class variable, but I'd like to reduce the scope as much as possible.
I could make it a function's attribute, but I suspect the assignment is repeated in every call.

Comment: You could prepend an `__` before the variable name, which will force python to mangle it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks, I think it deserves a full answer, especially if you explain mingling :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You don't have to

The code is fine as you posted it (the scope is minimal and creation of such a small set does not take enough time to bother about it.

However, if you like to change the code, here is one suggestion:

## Make it a default parameter

If you like to **avoid repeated creation** of the `chars_to_clean` set, you could do the following (see ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/5069869)):

```
def clean_word(word, chars_to_clean = {',', ':', '.','/'})
    res = ''
    for c in word:
        if c not in chars_to_clean:
            res += c
    return res
```

This way the set is crated only once (when python reads the function definition) and you can reuse the function to clean different characters. This is **dangerous**, if you mutate the set (accidentally), which you do not do here anyway.

## Make it upper case

If you want to make it clear (by convention) that this variable is a constant, change the variable name to all uppercase and don't bother about the scope

## Make it a string

You can do `"a" in "abcde"` in python. By changing it from a set to aa string, you can make it **immutable**. (Reassignment is however still possible)

## Make it a class property without setter

If you want to avoid accidental reassignment/ modification, make it a class property without setter. This solution is, however, probably an overkill.

```
class A:
    @property
    def chars_to_clean(self):
        return ",:./"
```

In this case, you can still do `A.chars_to_clean = "abc"`, but `A().chars_to_clean="asd"` and `A().chars_to_clean[0]=w` will raise an error, the first due to the missing setter, the second due to immutability of strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so many good suggestions! Re "don't have to", I guess you're right, but this function is going to be called for every word in many text file, so I'd like to save where it's obvious, even though it is kind of premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

A function is an object so you can set attributes on the object and use them. They are not "private" but when reading code you can see they are closely related.

So something like that :

```
def clean_word(word):
    res = ''
    for c in word:
        if c not in clean_word.chars_to_clean:
            res += c
    return res

clean_word.chars_to_clean = {',', ':', '.','/'}
```

It is not very elegant as you have to define the *chars_to_clean* after defining the function.

Another option where you would define the attribute while defining the function but the check *hasattr* is not very nice either :

```
def clean_word(word):
    if not hasattr(clean_word, 'chars_to_clean'):
        clean_word.chars_to_clean = {',', ':', '.','/'}     
    res = ''
    for c in word:
        if c not in clean_word.chars_to_clean:
            res += c
    return res
```